# Android fetch price of purchase using AndroidBillingLibrary

Tags: android, android-billing

I am using AndroidBillingLibrary for purchasing. But I don't know how to get the price of purchase (in-app item) in code. If it possible using the library, because this library based on In-app Billing API version 2? I saw that it is possible in API version 3 [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-requests)

Comment: so why can't you use API version 3 if it works there? because it's too different?

Comment: I already use API version 3

Comment: ok, so i've added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. But I implemented in-app Billing version 3. This is not so hard, there is a great and very simple documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html). Also Google provide a sample which anyone can download and use [how to install sample](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)

Answer (score 0):

if you use API3 of the in-app billing library,  this feature is already there.

it seems it's called "[getSkuDetails](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails)" .

for more information, watch the google IO 2013 lecture "In-App Billing Version 3" : https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324958374 , slides 104-107 .

you can also read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)...

sadly, even though they've added many nice features and made it easier, they've removed the feature of unmanaged purchases, but that's a different story.

Comment: I know this, I posted the same answer for my question.

Comment: so i still don't understand the question and the problem. if you already have the solution and used it, why to ask about it?

Comment: I asked when I did not know a solution